# Formula Field to display value in the number field

Tags: lightning, formula-field, validation-rule, default-value

I have an object called (Object1) 'Vechiel' and that has following fields like -  'Age'-(Number) 'Type'-(Picklist) and Max_Term-(Number).
And one more object called(Object2) - 'Application', which  has 'Age_of_Vehicle'-(Number), FacilityType-(Picklist) and Term(Formula Field).

Whenever I choose Age_of_Vechicle and FacilityType from Application object that need to fetch data from Max_Term(Object 1)  and display in the Term field which is in the Application.

Need forumla field to validate this one, Any help.
Thanks.

Comment: SFSE is not an implementation service. Please make sure to share with the community _what you've tried_ and _where you're stuck_ when you post. You can learn more about our format at [ask] and [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

Your Application object would need to be related to the Vehicle Object firstly for it to fetch a value from Vehicle. If you want to validate the 'Age_of_Vehicle' and 'FacilityType' for blank values before setting the 'Term' field, you could use a formula like this :

```
 IF( NOT( ISBLANK( Age_of_Vehicle ) ||  ISBLANK( FacilityType ) ),  Vehicle.Term , '')
```